# My webpage gets messed up upon changing window size

Tags: html, css

I'm having great difficulty trying to make my website not move when seen in different screen. It appears more messed up on mobile screen then on computer screen. Here is my code.

```
<html>
          <head>
          <style>
           #logo img {
            width: 120px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-left:350px;
            }
            #footer img {
            width: 450px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-left:250px;
            }
            #girl img {
            width: 450px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-left:200px;
            }
            #follow_us img {
            width: 250px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-left:300px;
            }
            img.NICE {
                position: absolute;
                left: 200px;
                top: 0px;
                z-index: -1;
            }
            body, div, dl, dt, dd, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, pre, code, blockquote {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            border-width:0;
          }
          body {
            -epub-hyphens:auto;
          }
          div.Basic-Text-Frame {
            border-style:solid;
          }
          p.Basic-Paragraph {
            color:#000000;
            font-family:"Minion Pro", serif;
            font-size:12px;
            font-style:normal;
            font-variant:normal;
            font-weight:normal;
            line-height:1.2;
            margin-bottom:0;
            margin-left:0;
            margin-right:0;
            margin-top:0;
            orphans:1;
            page-break-after:auto;
            page-break-before:auto;
            text-align:left;
            text-decoration:none;
            text-indent:0;
            text-transform:none;
            widows:1;
          }
          p.ParaOverride-1 {
            text-align:justify;
            text-align-last:center;
          }
          span.CharOverride-1 {
            color:#525358;
            font-family:Raleway, sans-serif;
            font-size:16px;
            font-style:normal;
            font-weight:200;
          }
          span.CharOverride-2 {
            font-family:Raleway, sans-serif;
            font-size:16px;
            font-style:normal;
            font-weight:200;
          }
          span.CharOverride-3 {
            color:#98c3d0;
            font-family:Raleway, sans-serif;
            font-size:16px;
            font-style:normal;
            font-weight:200;
          }
          span.CharOverride-4 {
            color:#f9a05d;
            font-family:Raleway, sans-serif;
            font-size:16px;
            font-style:normal;
            font-weight:200;
          }
          span.CharOverride-5 {
            color:#31373c;
            font-family:Raleway, sans-serif;
            font-size:8px;
            font-style:normal;
            font-weight:normal;
          }
          span.CharOverride-6 {
            font-family:Raleway, sans-serif;
            font-size:8px;
            font-style:normal;
            font-weight:normal;
          }
          span.CharOverride-7 {
            color:#525358;
            font-family:Raleway, sans-serif;
            font-size:9px;
            font-style:normal;
            font-weight:600;
          }
          a.button {
            background: url(http://i.imgur.com/tnWFc1M.png) 1px 5px no-repeat;
              background-size: 100px 20px;
              border: none;
              color: white;
              padding: 25px 35px;
              text-align: center;
              text-decoration: none;
              display: inline-block;
              font-size: 6px;
              margin: 9px 300px;
              cursor: pointer;
              -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
              transition-duration: 0.4s;
          }
          a.button1 {
              background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Dh3VnPe.png) 2px 6px no-repeat;
              background-size: 101px 22px;
              border: none;
              color: white;
              padding: 25px 40px;
              text-align: center;
              text-decoration: none;
              display: inline-block;
              font-size: 6px;
              margin: -65px 400px;
              cursor: pointer;
              -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
              transition-duration: 0.4s;
          }

          </style>
          </head>
          <div id="logo_info">
           <p id="logo"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/aukUVxR.png" alt="Bethan Rainforth a comedic dancer">
           </p>
          </div>
          <body id="TEXT" lang="en-US">

              <div id="_idContainer000" class="Basic-Text-Frame">
              <div id="header">

              <hr>
              </div>
              <p class="Basic-Paragraph ParaOverride-1"><span class="CharOverride-1">our</span><span class="CharOverride-2"> </span><span class="CharOverride-3">name</span><span class="CharOverride-2"> </span><span class="CharOverride-1">is our</span><span class="CharOverride-2"> </span><span class="CharOverride-4">mission</span></p>
              </div>
              <div id="_idContainer001" class="Basic-Text-Frame">
                <p class="Basic-Paragraph ParaOverride-1"><span class="CharOverride-5">We are a non-profit organization, founded by a medical doctor and eye surgeon.  </span></p>
                <p class="Basic-Paragraph ParaOverride-1"><span class="CharOverride-5">Our mission is to help people access vision care more effectively and conveniently.  </span></p>
                <p class="Basic-Paragraph ParaOverride-1"><span class="CharOverride-5">We prioritize low-income children and members of underserved communities by </span></p>
                <p class="Basic-Paragraph ParaOverride-1"><span class="CharOverride-5">delivering eyecare for free to pre-schools, after-school programs, community centers </span></p>
                <p class="Basic-Paragraph ParaOverride-1"><span class="CharOverride-5">and events.  We also extend our services to individuals who are able to pay for </span></p>
                <p class="Basic-Paragraph ParaOverride-1"><span class="CharOverride-5">exceptional eyecare delivered with the ease and convenience of services like Uber </span></p>
                <p class="Basic-Paragraph ParaOverride-1"><span class="CharOverride-5">and Lyft.  We will come to you and provide unprecedented levels of access to doctors.  </span></p>
                <p class="Basic-Paragraph ParaOverride-1"><span class="CharOverride-5">Being a non-profit organization, money collected helps us increase awareness of health </span></p>
                <p class="Basic-Paragraph ParaOverride-1"><span class="CharOverride-5">and education and provide free services to those who otherwise cannot afford it. </span><span class="CharOverride-6"> </span></p>
                <p class="Basic-Paragraph ParaOverride-1"><span class="CharOverride-7">To schedule an exam, please select from the following:</span></p>
              </div>
              <div id="buttonsz">

                  <a href="http://www.willgrantvision.com" class="button">Go to WillGrant</a>
                  <a href="http://www.willgrantvision.com" class="button1">Go to WillGrant</a>
              </div>
              <hr>

            <div id="header">
                <p id="girl"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ac4JwDA.png" alt="Bethan Rainforth a comedic dancer">
                <p id="girl"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/FXF5Ysh.png" alt="Bethan Rainforth a comedic dancer">

                </p>
                  <p id="follow_us"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZU53otY.png" alt="Bethan Rainforth a comedic dancer">

                </p>

            </div>
            </body>
          </html>
```

Here's an expected output.
[image]

Comment: This is a whole concept in web development called responsiveness... I would recommend utilizing flexbox which will help you control element positions inside your containers especially when the screen is resized.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking doesn't have a simple answer. Responsive design is what you are asking for. A couple of quick suggestions to assist with different screen sizes is using percentages instead of px, and using [max-width](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp) and [max-height](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp). Google responsive design and you'll find plenty of resources to help with your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Well, yea. For example:

```
 #logo img {
   width: 120px;
   margin-top: 20px;
   margin-left:350px;
 }
```

You probably did this on your screen and it looks ok. But once you move to a bigger/smaller screen, those 120px might mean something completely different. You have two options: 1) use media queries and try to cover as much screen resolutions as you can. 2) use some framework that has this almost resolved.

Option 1 will take quite some work. Option 2 will be easier, but you still will need to learn the framework. I recommend Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/

On a side not, it would help to use percentages (%) instead of pixels. No guarantee it will look nice, but it will be less of a mess than with pixels.